# error during Apex 3.2.1 installation

Tags: oracle-apex

i am installing Apex 3.2.1, encounter some errors:

command: @apexins SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/
error display after few minutes:

> VII.   L O A D    E N G L I S H   D I C T I O N A R Y
>
> Trigger altered.
>
> ...10000 rows
>
> ...20000 rows
>
> ...30000 rows
>
> ...40000 rows
>
> ...50000 rows
>
> ...60000 rows
>
> ...70000 rows
>
> timing for: English Dictionary
>
> Elapsed: 00:03:42.09
>
> begin
>
> *
>
> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-04042: procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist
>
> ORA-06512: at line 3
>
> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running an upgrade?

According to this [thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=438731&start=15&tstart=0) you might have an older version of Apex not correctly installed.

One option would be to uninstall Apex and re-install from scratch.

Comment: In that case I'd restart the installation from scratch.